# Probability of songs by the same artist within a playlist

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I cannot figure this out by myself and thought here might be the right place to ask for some help. So in abstract, I've got a group consisting of two different sets. I want to know the probability of drawing x items of one group after another without redraws until the whole group is empty. I figured hypergeometric distribution might do the trick, but when I put it in my spreadsheet it somehow seemed flawed. Maybe one of you can give me pointers into the right direction?

**Example:**
Say, there is a playlist consisting of 300 songs and within this playlist are 100 songs of one specific artist (a). How likely is it that if the playlist is on shuffle 5 songs of artist (a) will be played one after another? Mind you, once a song is played, it will not be played again until all 300 songs have been played. Oh, and also the successful event (5 in a row) can happen multiple times obviously.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean> Do you mean the first 5 songs are artist (a) with the remaining songs in any order, or do you mean that at some point there is one and only one sequence of exactly 5 songs by artist (a)...or what? In any event please show what you have tried.

Comment: Terribly sorry, what I meant was that within this set of 300, there could be multiple occurrences of 5 songs in a row. To me, it doesn't matter at which point, just that there is a probability of them to occur. Does this help?

Comment: I've been pondering your question over and over again and get more confused by every minute. Say the artist (a) has 100 songs, then the event of 5-in-a-row could happen 20 times at max or none at all at minimum. However, I figured there would be a possibility p attached to this event (however many) occurring within 300 songs having been played.

Comment: I think your problem is phrased clearly.  And it's probably easier to think about the complementary event, namely that "at no point in the $300$ long permutation do we get $5$ consecutive songs from $A$".  Letting $P(A,B)$ be the probability of this (with  $A$ songs from artist $A$ and $B$ from somebody else), you then want $1-P(100,200)$.  This can be computed recursively, though you'd want to automate it.

Comment: To set up the recursion, note that you must get a "$B$" song in the first $5$ or you fail right at the start.  As soon as you get a $B$ song the process restarts, but with smaller numbers.

Comment: @ShakeyKnight In fact 5-in-a-row could happen 96 times if you overlap them (so 7-in-a-row has three overlapping cases of 5-in-a-row).  You could answer a different question of the expected number of cases of 5-in-a-row, which I suspect is about $1.14$ with these $300,100,5$ numbers. Since this will sometimes include overlaps or other multiple cases, it does not tell you the probability of it happening at least once, except to say that the probability seems to be reasonably large and is certainly not improbable

Comment: Wow, very well, thank you all for the quick reply's. Henry - you're probably right, however since the 6th, 7th etc. song in the row doesn't really matter to me, @lulu s approach seems to be hitting the nail on its head. I have to admit that I'm a bit out of my depth here though. My end goal is a simple spreadsheet Formula, could you give me any pointers to come up with that specific recursion function?

Comment: Might be worth adding:  it is easy to compute the expected number of "$5-$runs from $A$".  There are $295$ places such a run might start, and the probability that a given place is the start of such a run is $\frac {100}{300}\times \frac {99}{299}\times \cdots \times \frac {96}{296}=.003845$. Multiplying by $295$ gives us an expected number of $1.134$

Comment: I believe the recursion (using my notation) is $P(A,B)=B\sum_{i=0}^4 \frac {A!}{(A-i)!}\times \frac {(A+B-i-1)!}{(A+B)!} P(A-i,B-1)$  Though you should check this!  easy to make an off-by-one error (these are my speciality so the probability that I made one is high).

Comment: A spreadsheet should work, you'll just need to work with a $200\times 100$ array to hold the various states.

Comment: @lulu minor point: $296$ rather than $295$ places it can start

Comment: @Henry  Oh, thank you.  I believe I mentioned that I specialize in off-by-one errors.

Comment: Correcting my error in the computation of the expected value:  I should have multiplied by $296$ instead of $295$, so the expected value is $1.138$

Comment: Thank you all so much for helping me out here. I really need to fresh up on my mathematics. Unfortunately, though, Google Spreadsheet cannot compute any factorial larger than 170, so this has been a rather theoretical exercise, haha. Thanks anyways! (: